# Help need to learn Quantum Computation and Information

Tags: reference-request, education, quantum-computing

I want to learn quantum computation and information. I am studying from Nielsen & Chuang book for this.
Is there any online vedio (lecture series) starts from
basics of quantum computation and information up to factorization, discrete log, search etc?

Comment: There was an excellent course on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) near the end of Summer by Umesh Vazirani. I would check for the next installment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't watched them myself, but you could probably do worse than Michael Nielsen's videos, [Quantum Computing for the Determined](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/quantum-computing-for-the-determined/).

I'd recommend also that you look online for written lecture notes; there is a very strong culture in the field of having students scribe notes which then have a habit of finding their way online. These can sometimes vary substantially in quality, but often the lecturer will take them and edit them, resulting in quite a good set of notes. Just as an example that I grabbed off the top of Google, [Ronald de Wolf's lecture notes](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/qcnotes.pdf) seem fairly comprehensive; but others surely exist, and if you find the going hard with those notes, you will probably find one set of notes which better suits your learning style.